# Can CPP Qt GUI can be integrated into PyQt?

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

I have an open source software written in C++ Qt. I need a UI which is in C++ Qt in my Python app.

Is it possible to embed that UI into my Python Qt.

Comment: Not sure what you exactly want to do, but `.ui` files, as edited by the designer, should(\*) be compatible with both C++ and Python backends. ((*): I never did that.)

Comment: @leemes But is it possible to integrate that UI file along with its cpp code into my python app?

Comment: We're now talking about the manually written C++ code (which probably implements UI behavior and things like that)? I'm not sure about that. But in general Python and C++ are interoperable, so it should be possible somehow, and the way how you do it shouldn't depend on Qt. In the end you have two different and independent Qt libraries... The "normal" C++ Qt and PyQt.

Comment: So i guess i have to see how to make both of them interoperable.

Comment: @UsualSuspect. You could provide your own python bindings for your C++ code. If you want to use pyqt, the most obvious tool to do that with would be [sip](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/introduction.html).